# PasswordBox C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Здрастувуйте! Как сделать чтобы при выборе `CheckBox` пароль скрывался  и наоборот, все никак не могу понять.

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17007686/9024827) явно говорится, что такая функциональность не заложена в `PasswordBox`. Используйте `TextBox`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вам уже сказали, такой функциональности нет у `PasswordBox`. Но я предложу решение-костыль, которое как-то реализовал. У нас есть `TextBox`, `PasswordBox`, `CheckBox` и `Button`.

```
<TextBox Name="pwdTextBox" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="409,576,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="170" Visibility="Hidden"/>
<PasswordBox Name="pwdPasswordBox" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="409,576,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="170"/>
<CheckBox Name="checkBoxPwd" Content="Show password" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="452,547,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="CheckBox_Click"/>
<Button Content="Submit" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="452,617,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
```

- `TextBox` - тут будет виден пароль
- `PasswordBox` - тут будет скрыт пароль
- `CheckBox` - переключатель видимости пароля
- `Button` - кнопка для отображения пароля в окне

Главное условие - это расположение `TextBox` и `PasswordBox` в одном и том же месте с одними и теми же координатами. Просто установить одинаковые значения. `TextBox` изначально убдет скрыт. Обработчик клика на `CheckBox` будет таким:

```
private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var checkBox = sender as CheckBox;
    if (checkBox.IsChecked.Value)
    {
        pwdTextBox.Text = pwdPasswordBox.Password; // скопируем в TextBox из PasswordBox
        pwdTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // TextBox - отобразить
        pwdPasswordBox.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; // PasswordBox - скрыть
    }
    else
    {
        pwdPasswordBox.Password = pwdTextBox.Text; // скопируем в PasswordBox из TextBox 
        pwdTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; // TextBox - скрыть
        pwdPasswordBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // PasswordBox - отобразить
    }
}
```

Ну а по нажатию на кнопку отобразим наш пароль, это для наглядности:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var passrod = checkBoxPwd.IsChecked.Value ? pwdTextBox.Text : pwdPasswordBox.Password;
    MessageBox.Show(passrod);
}
```

Данный пример польносью рабочий. Да, костыль, но это самое простое решение.

Ссылка на очень похожий ответ с большого SO: [showing password characters on some event for passwordbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10092778/5275890) можно еще `Focus` добавить, как сделано там.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10092778/6125029

Comment: @Birdy - оригинал у меня на компьютере :) но ссылку добавил, спасибо

Comment: Правильней, наверное, это с помощью конвертеров делать.

Comment: @Mirdin думаю, если вы опубликуете еще один ответ - лишним это не будет. Я привел пример быстрого и простого способа всего лишь.

Comment: пожалуй, можно "костылить" ещё проще :) по установке/сбросу галочки в CheckBox'е заполнить/очистить всплывающую подсказку(ToolTip) самого PasswordBox'а.

Comment: @Alias пожалуй, что да, но пароль будет в тултипе отображаться, а хотельсь бы прямо в текстовом поле его увидеть :)

Comment: тут можно вывернуться -- подсказка это всплывающий объект, а не только лишь строчка, создадим System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip, настроим его и присвоим PasswordBox'у, например так:


`ToolTip tooltip = new ToolTip();`
`tooltip.BorderBrush = null;//нет_границы`
`tooltip.HasDropShadow = false;//нет_тени`
`tooltip.Placement=System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Relative;//поверх_пароля`
`tooltip.StaysOpen=true;//оставаться`
`tooltip.Content=passwordBox.Password;`
`passwordBox.ToolTip=tooltip;//установка_объекта_подсказки`


Но над оформлением ещё придётся поработать  :)

Comment: @Alias, может в качестве ответа офрмите? :) звучит многообещающе :)

Answer (score 2):

Как отмечено выше, хоть непосредственно такого функционала у PasswordBox нет, (!)но возможно реализовать *несколько* *костыльное* *решение* через собственную всплывающую подсказку самого PasswordBox'а, которая есть объект (а не только лишь строчка) -- создадим System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip, настроим его и по установке/сбросу галочки в CheckBox'е будем заполнять/очищать подсказку PasswordBox'у, например так:

```
private void checkBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)//на установку/снятие галочки
{
    if (checkBox.IsChecked == true)
    {
        ToolTip tooltip = new ToolTip();
        tooltip.BorderBrush = null;//нет границы
        tooltip.HasDropShadow = false;//не отбрасывать тень
        tooltip.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Relative;//поверх элемента
        tooltip.StaysOpen = true;//оставаться открытым
        tooltip.Content = passwordBox.Password;//собственно текст подсказки = незамаскированный пароль

        passwordBox.ToolTip = tooltip;//установка
    }
    else
    {
        passwordBox.ToolTip = null;//сброс
    };
}
```

конечно, над оформление ещё стоит поработать :) и лучше такой спец. ToolTip создавать единственный раз вместе с окном пароля.